# Special Reordering with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure out a way to reorder items on mobile `md` with the `col-` class to achieve this:

Desktop:

```
[1]    [4]
[2]    [5]
[3]
[6]
[7]
```

Mobile:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
```

Is there a way to get that without using `hidden-md-` class and duplicate the content?

HTML from ZimSystem:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block long block 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to get the content of the block 6 to be just bellow the block 3 (see picture)
[image]

Comment: I got a solution. Works fine when there is a lot of text. I posted a JsFiddle and the needed code in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nesting like this..

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    1
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    2
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    4
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    5
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    6
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    7
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Flexbox grid demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/DGM9D7xSnz)

***Edit*** - Based on the new "height" issue, flexbox will not work for this. The best way to achieve this is using the float utilities.

[Float grid demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/Qivv76bHM0)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks <3

Comment: Just updated the question, in fact that's what I thought would happen but not what I had exactly in mind. Can you take a look?

Answer (score -1):

This should work (even mobile). Here a link to the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oauhn5d/).

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                4
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                6
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If you are having other problems with

- the migration
- all the new classes
- etc.

in the newest Version of Bootstrap (v4.0.0-alpha.6) you can check this [Bootstrap Site](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) out.

I hope I could answer you any further questions and helping all other people which are having problems. :)

Comment: You should answer the question specifically.

Comment: @ZimSystem added the code. Is the answer fine, now?